# Why do I need to declare the length in the forloop and not use it directily?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function to capitalize the first letter of every word in the string that I use as attribute.

But I can't figure it out why I need to declare in the for loop the length of the split and not use it directly.

This is the code that works:

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
    wordarr = str.split(" ");

    for (var i = 0, n = wordarr.length; i < n; i++) {
        wordarr[i] = wordarr[i][0].toUpperCase() + wordarr[i].slice(1); 
    }
    str = wordarr.join(" ");

    return str; 
}
```

The problem that I have: I don't understand why this works:

```
  for (var i = 0, n = wordarr.length; i < n; i++) {...
```

but this doesn't:

```
  for (var i = 0, i < wordarr.length; i++) {...
```

Thanks for any advice that you guys can give me.

Comment: A `for` loop has three statements separated by semicolons -  `;`  Try: `for (var i = 0;  i < wordarr.length; i++)` (note the semicolon after the zero, not a comma).

Comment: Once you change that comma to a semicolon as noted by @MarkMeyer, your code should work fine.  However, there are performance considerations when doing it this way.  The variable `wordarr.length` will actually be COUNTED on every iteration.  I would actually stick to your original code as it should be more performant.

Comment: Do you really think there's a performance benefit there worth worrying about @SteveDanner? `length` is a property on the array, not something that's calculated each time. It should be as fast as a looking up any other property.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so, thinking about the performance considerations, should I use the 'n' declaration for all my forloops in the future?

Comment: @SteveDanner  Be careful when optimizing JS, due to the way JIT compiling works etc, assuming the first version is faster is wrong.  In fact in Chrome the second version of comparing length directly is actually faster.

Comment: @Keith, thanks!  I realize now that is an outdated piece of advice I never bothered to "update".  Good to know as the second version is MUCH cleaner too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forloop has three statements. Initialization, condition and incrementing. Each statement is separated by ';'. But in your forloop, initialization and condition parts are separated by ',' instead of ';'. Javascript thinks they both belong in one statement.

Following should work

for (var i = 0; i < wordarr.length; i++) {

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN "for" loop can have three blocks:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

statement
But in your case you use "," instead of ";".

This one should work perfectly for you

```html
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 

  wordarr = str.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0, n = wordarr.length; i < n; i++) {
   wordarr[i] = wordarr[i][0].toUpperCase() + wordarr[i].slice(1); 
  }
  str = wordarr.join(" ");

  return str; 

}
```